# Which attribute selection method to use in clustering in R

Tags: r, classification, feature-selection

I have  a number of time series with around 5000 rows. Each row has 6 attributes and a class assigned. My problem is to determine which attributes are more effective in the classification using R, preferably (Similar to ANOVA analysis in regression where some of the variables are determined to be insignificant).

The attributes are qualitative as well as quantitive. How to handle qualitative ones? And more importantly how to determine which attributs are effective in classes?

Answer (score 0):

As categorical attributes. In R referred to as factors.

One way to compare classification accuracy is to remove an attribute and see how the accuracy of the model decreases.

Comment: Thanks @Ivo that was rather the simpler question actually. My main problem is: how to determine which attribute is effective in classes?

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: The problem here is that I already made the clustering previously, without the added parameters. Currently, I only have subjects with classes and totally newly defined 6 attribute. Hence, i donot have a model at hand. Only the result of classification.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. Do you want to built a classification model with these 6 attributes and test which of the 6 are good at classifying and which aren't? If yes, what is your question exactly.

Comment: No, I dont need a model. All I have is 6 variables and a class for 5000 rows. I need to find if variables 1,..,6 really are effective in classes or they are not? I m looking at Boruto package, it looks promising.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "effective in classes"?

Comment: For a "not effective variable", no matter what value a variable X takes, it cannot change the class. On the other hand, for an efective variable there is a strong correlation between class and the value of that variable.

Comment: OK. So you are now describing the process of a general classification model. You have a categorical outcome variable (with several classes), and you have several attributes that you want to test for their ability to distinguishing those classes. This is a form of (supervised) classification. A multinomial logistic regression could do the trick, but I don’t know for sure as I have no clue what kind of data you have.